# iOS FFT on a file from iPod library

Tags: ios, xcode, core-audio, fft

I'm new to core audio and I've been banging my head against a brick wall for a while on how to do this and I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

I'm creating an app for an assignment and I want the user to select a file from the iPod library (MPMediaPickerontroller ?) and then perform an fft on said file to detect the pitch.

I have code working that selects the file and saves it's location as an NSURL and I have code working for OSX that will play a file from a URL! I can't get this part to work on iOS for reasons that are beyond me.

I've also seen lots of sample code that implements FFT using remote i/o to fill the buffers but I can't work out how to do this from the iPod library.

Can anyone help? Idealluy point me to some sample code that will show me how best to do some of these tasks? I've looked at previous threads and can't see anything that's quite what I need.

Many thanks in Advance!

Comment: Note that an FFT alone is not a good pitch detector or estimator.

Comment: Especially if the source audio files contains many parts.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a NSURL Link to your songs, why not try using `AVFoundation` for the FFT part. Since you have the url it is perfect because the player in `AVFoundation` imports songs by URL.